# Leaflet change map style based on Maritime Borders or own JSON

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

Is it possible to change the maps style after a particular maritime border or a polyline geo JSON?

I'm trying to change the color of the sea after a maritime border. is there any chance to change it? I'm using leaflet js.

[image]

I want to change the sea as red color after the red border.

Comment: You need to cover it with a red polygon.

Comment: Or get tiles that have the border/coloring you want.

Comment: @geocodezip, I can able to change whole sea color as red. But I need to change the color after the border only. I'm trying to cover the maritime border of India. I didn't get your Red Polygon point. Could you explain or attach a image or sample ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

we can use geo JSON and be using leaflet ajax js.

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("xxx.geojson", {
            style: function (feature) { // Style option
                console.log("feature", feature);
                return {
                    'weight'    : 1,
                    'color'     : 'black',
                    'fillColor' : 'yellow'
                }
            }
        });   
        geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a line like this

[image: line]

Just add some points to the start and end, somewhat far away, making a closed line...

[image: closed line]

...and use that as a polygon.

[image: polygon]

Please remember that the earth is round, so you cannot simply "colour things differently to the left/right of a line", because you will come back to the other side:

[image: boundaries wrapping]

You must decide how to close the area. Maybe you want to cover a whole country, maybe you want to cover half of the earth. You have to choose. For example, this might be perfectly acceptable for your scenario:

[image: boundary not wrapping]